# Pressure spike due to the water hammer

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to calculate pressure spike when valve is open in the depicted system.
We have two volumes separated by a valve. We have pressure on one side of the valve (P1). Other side is at 0 pressure. Both volumes are constant and are full with incompressible fluid.

Then we open the valve instantly and pressure wave travels until it hits a stop at the very end of the external pipe. How to calculate maximum pressure value at this point?

[image]

Comment: Water hammer typically occurs when a moving stream of water is suddenly stopped by a valve.  Because you are starting from a static condition and both containers are full of an incompressible fluid, there will be very little pressure spike in the "V2" container, and the pressures will equalize very quickly.  Assuming that this is a real world problem, what are you worried about regarding a pressure spike?

Comment: I want to know if sudden stop of pressure wave at the blind end can generate higher pressure than what was on the left of the valve before it was open.

Comment: My guess is "no", but I seriously doubt that you or I can find any documentation to back up that assumption, because the available documentation on water hammer involves a flowing stream that is suddenly stopped by a quickly closing valve, which isn't the case that you asked about.